# How to get assert to print to UART? STM32 newlib nano

Tags: c, stm32, newlib

Context:  STM32, newlib nano, GCC-ARM, C/C++, FreeRTOS

I would like my assert statements to print to the UART.  printf works perfectly.  I can also get assert to print an error message to the UART, but only if I do a fprint(stderr, "\n") before any asserts.  However, I need to do this once per thread or the first write to stderr does nothing.

Note that this first fprintf("\n") never actually prints anything and doesn't call _write_r, but any following fprintf's do!

Does anyone have any hints on how to correctly hook these calls so I don't have to do a fprintf("\n") on every new thread?  I have the following newlib nano weak functions overridden:

```
size_t _write(FILE* instance, const char* bp, size_t n)
{
    return UARTWrite(gDbgUARTHndl, bp, n);
}

int _write_r(void *reent, int fd, char *ptr, size_t len)
{
    return _write((FILE*)fd, ptr, len);
}

void someFunc(void)
{
    // If this function is the first called (on a particular thread) it doesn't print the assertion
    assert(false); 
}


void someOtherFunc(void)
{
    // If this function is the first called (on a particular thread) it DOES print the assertion (bot not the first "\n")
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    assert(false); 
}
```

NOTE: _write is called by any printf or puts calls.  _write_r is called by assert ([via __assert_func calling fprintf](https://github.com/32bitmicro/newlib-nano-2/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/assert.c)).

Comment: @somanyquestions - You added an answer post that was actually a comment (due to your limited privileges), saying  "I haven't run into this particular issue. But I use STM32 and wondering: 
**(a)** did you happen to check your UART settings? Is there something limiting it there?
**(b)** have you run in debug mode and take out all the newline prints, force a certain order to happen, throw it in debug mode and see what is happening?"

Comment: Have you considered if there are any race conditions between the task that launches the UART shell output, and the actual UART transmission?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The UART is configured fine and there are no race conditions in any of the application code.  The _write function is never called so there is never even a write made to the UART.  I am guessing this is some subtlety to the newlib nano fprintf.  I did already look in newlib source and couldn't see any reason why _write would not be called.  To clarify, this issue only occurs if an assert statement is the first thing to print output per thread.  If a printf is the first thing, then there is no problem and following asserts will print fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have run across this as well and it happens because of a bug in newlib.

Basically, the first time you call certain functions it will initialize the stdio package, and from what I recall it needs a call to setvbuf() on stderr that happens here.

Unfortunately not all functions contain the initialized check, and again from memory I think it might have be the fputc(XXX, stderr) which does not contain the needed initialization. At any rate assert() is writing stderr via one of the functions that doesn't auto initialize.

If my recollection is correct then it would be tricky to fix because for fgetc() and fputc() to work via macros the buffer created by setvbuf() needs to be available before the macro call, so it can quickly print into that buffer and only make a slower function call when full.

So the fix would somehow involve either declaring stderr and its buffer with all static variables in such a way that they are entirely ready to use at system startup, or else organizing for the C startup code to call newlib and initialize the stdio package. Neither is very easy.

My solution was similar to yours, just making a dummy call to one of the safe functions on startup. Although in my case I only seemed to need the workaround it once before starting the RTOS scheduler, I didn't do it once per thread. So perhaps that would be a solution for you.

Well I realize it's an old question but answering anyway.